# Using a custom class file in Umbraco XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, umbraco

I'm trying to reference a custom class file in XSLT code. I deployed it as a DLL file to the /Bin directory.

Keep getting this error:

> System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Cannot find the script or external object that implements prefix 'urn:sso'.

CS File Declarations:

```
namespace SSOUtilities
{
      public class sso
```

XSLT Reference:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:sso="urn:sso"
xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:umbraco.contour="urn:umbraco.contour" 
exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets umbraco.contour sso">
```

config/xsltExtensions.config declaration:

```
<ext assembly="/bin/SSOUtilities" type="SSOUtilities.sso" alias="sso" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a syntax issue in the xsltExtensions.config

```
  <ext assembly="/bin/Umbraco.Forms.Core" type="Umbraco.Forms.Library" alias="umbraco.contour">
  <ext assembly="/bin/SSOUtilities" type="SSOUtilities.sso" alias="sso" />
  </ext>
```

Notice the closing  tag which installing Contour placed in the file.

Answer (score 4):

In Umbraco 4.5 you no longer need to put the /bin/ in the config/xsltExtensions.config declaration so this may be causing your error if you are using Umbraco 4.5.

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/about/roadmap/umbraco-45/upgrading-to-umbraco-45

Comment: Good to know, Tim.  The version I'm current on is: 4.0.3

Comment: So what is the new way?

Answer (score 3):

Let me add another answer with a complete example of one of my extensions. The class Embed.cs:

```
using System.Web;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;

namespace Omega.XsltExtensions
{
    public class Embed
    {
        public static void LogEmbed(int nodeId)
        {
            Log.Add(LogTypes.Open, new User(0), nodeId, "Embedded pano, referer: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is being built as Omega.XsltExtensions.dll and copied to Umbraco's /bin directory.

In my xsltExtensions.config I've added:

```
<ext assembly="/bin/Omega.XsltExtensions" type="Omega.XsltExtensions.Embed" alias="Ext.Embed" />
```

An empty XSLT file that uses this extension looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" 
xmlns:Ext.Embed="urn:Ext.Embed"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets Ext.Embed ">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="Ext.Embed:LogEmbed($currentPage/@id)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hopefully you can spot any omissions in your version when you compare it to this one.

Answer (score 1):

You should add "sso" to your exclude-result-prefixes as well, the should make it work.

Also, your class should inherit from ApplicationBase and I'm not sure if a static class will work:

```
public class sso : ApplicationBase
```

And that is using umbraco.BusinessLogic if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Without the quotes, I hope? :)

Comment: Hah, ya, without the quotes.  Let me try the inherit you mentioned. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Removed the static and made it a public class. As for inheriting from ApplicationBase, I'm using an example which I've verified works.  It does not inherit from ApplicationBase. Any other thoughts? This one is really stumping me.